# Android Is It possible to get cache directory path with package name?

Tags: android, caching

I am developing a application need to clean specific application cache data, like device setting clear app cache button, I already find out the clear data solution, but how can I find out that application cache data directory so that I can remove that cache folder?

Big Thanks.

Comment: To get cache path, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir() . To get package name, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for delete cache of your own application then simply delete your cache  directory and its all done !

```
public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
    try {
        File dir = context.getCacheDir();
        deleteDir(dir);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    } else if(dir!= null && dir.isFile()) {
        return dir.delete();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And you may require following permission to add in your manifest file in order to delete cache of other application

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"/>
```